# Dropdownlist data binding inside detailsview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have detailsview that will be used to edit customer records. Inside this detailsview, I have a dropdownlist that shows list of countries.

I have a table called CountryList that will populate list of countries to the above dropdownlist.

User can edit and save data without any issue.

But, assume that customer record has the country selected as "Australia" and if I delete Australia from the CountryList and try to edit the customer inside the details view, I am getting below error.

```
SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items
```

I know the reason because the

```
SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Country") %>'
```

and it can't find it in the list.

So my question is, how to overcome this issue  ?

After searching the web, I found that I can override the Databind but I am not sure how to do this. Have no idea how to override and can someone please give me sample code ?

Also is there any other solution for this such as validate it before set ?

Thank you.

Comment: use this SelectedValue= '<%# dropdownId.Items.IndexOf(dropdownId.Items.FindByValue(Eval(Country)))>%'> you may have to check for the syntax

Comment: Why would you not maintain foreign key constraints when you delete data? Seems like you are avoiding the root cause and trying to fix the symptom.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the existence of the country in your list(dataTable,DataSet etc) before binding ,some thing like

```
DataTable dtPs=getAvailableCountries();
string countryName = "Australia";
DataRow foundRow = dtPs.Rows.Find(countryName);
if(foundRow != null) {
 //You have it ...
 bindTheDropdown();
}else{
 //You dont have it ...
 dontBindTheDropdown();
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where exactly I should put this code and call it ? It is inside a detailsview and in can't figure out where to add the code.  Also note it is twoway binding so Have to use Bind..

Comment: ok,you are retieving and saving the DB values(countries) in to result set(datatable,dataset etc) and binding in to dropdownlist,put this code before this binding.

Answer (score 0):

you can call function before selecting value as follows:

```
SelectedValue='<%# CheckCountry(Eval("Country"))%>'
```

in aspx.cs file create function as follows which will check whether country is exist in list or not if it is not there then will show default value as selected

```
public string CheckCountry(string country)
{
   // add your logic to check contry in list 
   //  and return value as per result if it is exist
   // return country name else return default value
}
```

Comment: I already tried this but it is two way binding so I have to use Bind instead of Eval that will not work and throw an error. ..